# Atomic transaction on django queryset.update(**kwargs)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

It seems `Django`'s `queryset.update` method execute under `transaction.atomic` context manager. When would I need to do that explicitly in my code during `update`? Or what will be the benefits doing it, or problems not doing it?

### Code

```
try:
    queryset = Model.objects.filter(a=1)
    if queryset.count():
        with transaction.atomic():
            queryset.update(a=2) # queryset will [] after this.
            for item in queryset: 
                item.emit_event('Updated')
except:
    logger.info('Exception')
```

My question is do I really need to have `transaction.atomic():` here?

Secondly, after `.update` my queryset gets empty because its a filtered queryset. how to retain the values in my case as I want to emit an event on the individual objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 30.08.2023**

There is a new queryset method [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) in most cases you probably want to use it instead.

**First**

As [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) state

> Atomicity is the defining property of database transactions. atomic allows us to create a block of code within which the atomicity on the database is guaranteed. If the block of code is successfully completed, the changes are committed to the database. If there is an exception, the changes are rolled back.

In your example you would need `atomic` if `emit_event` is doing something and you want this update to be done only if all `emit_event` function calls and `queryset.update` are successfull. But if states of `emit_event` does not affect your business logic of update, `atomic` here would be redundant because as you said yourself `update` has internal `atomic`.

**Second**

Querysets are lazy. Which means evaluation of queryset will be done when you are iterating over it. So you need to do something like this. Answering latest comment

```
try:
    queryset = Model.objects.filter(a=1)
    item_ids = list(queryset.values_list('id', flat=True)) # store ids for later
    if item_ids: # optimzing here instead of queryset.count() so there won't be hit to DB
        with transaction.atomic():
            queryset.update(a=2) # queryset will [] after this.
            for item in Model.objects.filter(id__in=item_ids):  # <- new queryset which gets only updated objects
                item.emit_event('Updated')
except:
    logger.info('Exception')
```

See there we make new queryset when iterating over it to get updated items

Comment: `emit_event` doesn't have to change the db in order for `atomic` to be useful. For example, it could make a request to an external api. If that raises an exception then the atomic block will roll back the update. However if it's not in an atomic block then the update will already have been committed.

Comment: @Alasdair yes. Thanks. Forgot about other external sources. Like cache, apis, etc, or just function calls.

Comment: The problem it will have that `items = list(queryset)` will save queryset with old values not updated values. Like attribute `a` would have value `1` rather than `2` after the update.

Comment: @Clayton Yes. I thought this is what you wanted. If not. Go with first suggested method.

Comment: Thanks, I would like the answer to be precise for the others. `Model.objects.filter(a=2)` would not be the actual queryset that was updated. Lets say we have 3 rows in db, 2 with `a=1` and one with `a=2`. After updating all 3 rows would have `a=2` and refetching `Model.objects.filter(a=2)` would get me all three rows. Not looking good right? let me check how we can overcome that, Almost there yeah :)

Comment: @Clayton See update. You would need to save ids of objects so you can filter by them with `id__in`

Comment: Perfect then, Just one nit, use `list()` wrapper for saving `item_ids`. +1